# SelectList from Entity List

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, selectlist

I have a list of entities in my view model:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public int SelectedItem {get; set;}
    public List<Meeting> Meetings {get; set;}
}
public class Meeting {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Info {get; set;}
}
```

In my view I have a dropdownlist to serve as a listbox (setting the size to 10), and I'm shortcutting the selectlist creation as I've seen in some examples:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem,
    new SelectList(Model.Meetings, "Meeting.Id", "Meeting.Title"),
    new {@id="itemList"})
```

This works in my first page load, when Meetings is an empty list.  But as soon as Meetings is populated I get a reference is not set to instance of object error.  I moved the creation of the selectlist into my controller with a similar thought:

```
ViewBag.mySelectList = new SelectList(ViewModel.Meetings, "Meeting.Id", "Meeting.Title")
```

and in the debugger I see that it the selectlist is there and includes the Meetings list, but the results view returns the error.  When I create it as I have normally done:

```
var selList = Meetings.Select(m => new SelectListItem {
    Value = m.Id.ToString(),
    Text = m.Title}).ToList();
mySelectList = new SelectList(selList, "Value", "Text");
```

And then return the view model (mySelectList is in the viewmodel for this to work) to the view it works.  This seems like the right approach but seeing examples of view code like mine above had me hopeful for smaller view models and controller code.  Is there some trick to creating the SelectList on the fly in the Razor page that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the strings "Meeting.Id" and "Meeting.Title" with the `nameof` expression. There are no quotes for the values in the `nameof` expression.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItem,
    new SelectList(Model.Meetings, nameof(Meeting.Id), nameof(Meeting.Title)),
    new {@id="itemList"})
```

The Razor `<select>` tag helper version:

```
<select id="itemList"
    asp-items="@new SelectList(Model.Meetings, nameof(Meeting.Id), nameof(Meeting.Title))"
    aria-label="List of meetings"></select>
```

Comment: Perfect . . . not sure why string literals no longer work.  But nameof is better, and lets intellisense also start to help.  In my case my ViewModel did not have a `Meeting` property, and after adding that to my ViewModel it works well, and no reason to create a separate SelectList in my ViewModel.

Comment: The string literals work if just "Id" and "Title" are used instead of "Meeting.Id" and "Meeting.Title". As you said, however, `nameof` is better because if the property used to identify the value field ("Id") or the text field ("Title") changed in your `Meeting` model, then the project won't compile. With `nameof`, fixes can be made at compile time versus a run time error in the view displaying the `select` element created by the `DropDownListFor` HTML Helper or `select` tag helper.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want  `<select asp-for="SelectedItem" asp-items="ViewBag.mySelectList"></select>`?

1.MVC demo

In HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       
        public List<Meeting> Meetinglist = new List<Meeting>()
        { new Meeting() { Id = 1,Title = "aa"},
            new Meeting() { Id = 2,Title = "bb"},
            new Meeting() { Id = 3,Title = "cc"}
        };
       

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.mySelectList = new SelectList(Meetinglist, "Id", "Title");
            var model = new ViewModel();
            model.SelectedItem = 2;//set bb selected
            return View(model);
        }  
   }
```

Index view:

```
@model ViewModel
<select asp-for="SelectedItem" asp-items="ViewBag.mySelectList"></select>
```

2.razor page demo

IndexModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public int SelectedItem { get; set; }
        public SelectList TagOptions { get; set; }             
        public List<Meeting> Meetinglist = new List<Meeting>() 
            { new Meeting() { Id = 1,Title = "aa"},
            new Meeting() { Id = 2,Title = "bb"},
            new Meeting() { Id = 3,Title = "cc"}
    };      
       
        public void OnGet()
        {            
            TagOptions = new SelectList(Meetinglist, "Id", "Title");
            SelectedItem = 2;
        }
    }
```

Index html:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<select asp-for="SelectedItem" asp-items="Model.TagOptions"></select>
```

result:

[image]